# Two ImageViews with the same xml properties acting differently in Android Relative layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-imageview

I have two imageviews in a relative layout. One keeps acting almost 3 times the width as the other. Both pngs are 60px x 60px, so I don't understand why one is being drawn 3 times as wide. The image is not stretched, it just takes up 3 times more width in the relative layout.

The two imageviews:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/linerlayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/container_ide"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="that"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_image" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="this"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image_two" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

They should (In my knowledge) behave exactly the same. As you can see in the screenshot below `@drawable/image_two` is acting way off. The bounding box being three times too wide is killing my layout. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine for me with different image.

So perhaps it is something to do with your image?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to test the code, but yes... I'm confused about why it's not working with this image. It is a .png, I'm confused.

Comment: Actually, I double check the images, and it seems the size of the circle is bigger, roughly by triple the width. But I thought imageView scales it down to fit in it's parent?

Comment: @EGHDK `ImageView` is trying to fit the original size of the image but since you have specified the height of the `RelativeLayout` so android just adding extra space while making the image best fit in the ImageView. You will see the difference if you change `RelativeLayout` to `android:layout_hight="wrap_content"`